# How to use content.pagination.current_page in controller as a bound value

Tags: ember.js, pagination, handlebars.js

I am using this example ( https://gist.github.com/tcjr/6935684 ) to implement server-side pagination in an Ember.js app. Using that example, Router places metadata about the pagination on the results content array directly.

At the template layer the code looks like this:

```
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
          <li><a {{action 'firstPage'}}>&lt;&lt;</a></li>
          <li><a {{action 'previousPage'}}>&lt;</a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a>{{ content.pagination.current_page }} of {{ content.pagination.total_pages }}</a></li>
          <li><a {{action 'nextPage'}}>&gt;</a></li>
          <li><a {{action 'lastPage'}}>&gt;&gt;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```

What I want to do is have a conditional so that if, for example, I'm on the first page the first two links are hidden. E.g. (using my latest helper attempt)

```
{{#ifGT content.pagination.current_page 1}}
    <li><a {{action 'firstPage'}}>&lt;&lt;</a></li>
    <li><a {{action 'previousPage'}}>&lt;</a></li>
{{/ifGT}}
```

But this doesn't work. Efforts to create a helper either return the string (i.e. the string 'content.pagination.current_page' > 1) or, if using `registerBoundHelper`, gives me the error: `registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.`.

```
// currently this fails with:
// registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('ifGT', function(val1, val2, options) {
  console.log(val1);
  console.log(val2);
  if(val1 > val2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

If a helper won't work (and maybe I'm just doing it wrong) how do I get access to the value of `content.pagination.current_page` from within the controller or route so that I can create a normal bound value use the normal Handlebars if block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work I ended up using the `setupController` function on the Route like this:

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  var pagination = model.get('pagination');
  var page = pagination.current_page;
  var total_pages = pagination.total_pages;
  controller.set('isFirstPage', page === 1);
  controller.set('isLastPage', page >= total_pages);
},
```

Once it was set up, I was able to reference the controller properties like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare various properties in the controller/component (or a mixin), for example:

```
isFirstPage: Ember.computed.equal('page', 1);
isFirstPageLinkEnabled: Ember.computed.not('isFirstPage');
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that the pagination metadata, when using that sample code from th gist, is placed on the `records` object and is not a property of the controller (I think... my ember terminology is failing).  That's why there's that weird `content.pagination.current_page` reference.

Comment: Code was meant to be an example. You should resolve was needs resolving in the controller and keep the template simple.